Robots.txt Validation Failed?!? Can't find any error. What am I missing?
This is my first post! I'm trying to work my way through the technical side of SEO by cleaning up some Google Search Console issues.
Google Search Console page report shows that validation failed for the following link (which is a tag link, and tags are blocked in my Robots.txt ...on purpose, or so I read).
I've been looking everywhere for a solution to this one, and either I can't find it, or I can't see it right in front of my face. Either way: stumped.

Image One: The Google Search Console Screen (links sanitized): Image
Image Two: Check link at Robots.txt validator. All Good!

Please advise as to what the heck I'm supposed to do to fix this error (or point me in the right direction). Thanks!
The Google Search Console Screen

Robots.txt validator


The "blocked by robots.txt" report within the Google Search Console shows all URLs that are blocked from crawling by the directives of your robots.txt file. If the URLs were blocked on purpose there is nothing to do. In this case the report is only a status report to give you a better understanding of what's going on.
Clicking on "Validate Fix" only makes sense if you accidently blocked URLs and want Google to recrawl and index them. To do so you would have to remove the directives that block the URLs prior to clicking "Validate Fix".
Note: Validating the fix will only be successful if all URLs listed in the report are crawlable afterwards. If a single URL remains blocked the validation will fail, however if you removed a single directive, the affected URLs will still be removed from this report after some time.
Hope this helps.
